# require handlebar plugin i18n only load default 'en_us.json'

Tags: internationalization, requirejs, handlebars.js

I try to use require-handlebars-plugin with i18n functionality.

But, Even if I change my browser language, require try to load the default file '**en_us.json**'.

I can set a **locale** value in require js config to "force" to load the right file. But I don't think it is the good way to "how use it".

```
define({
    name: 'The Handle of the Bars',
    require: {
        paths: {
            handlebars: 'components/require-handlebars-plugin/Handlebars',
            hbs: 'components/require-handlebars-plugin/hbs',
            i18nprecompile: 'components/require-handlebars-plugin/hbs/i18nprecompile',
            json2: 'components/require-handlebars-plugin/hbs/json2'
        },
//      locale: (navigator.language.substring(0, 2) === 'en') ? 'en' : 'fr',
        hbs: {
            disableI18n : false,
            disableHelpers: true,
            templateExtension: 'hbs'
        }
    },
```

What am I missing ? :)

---

Oh and I have also an other question :

Is it possible to set a default value if the language isn't found ?

For example, if the browser language is set to "de", but My application have only **en** and **fr** translations.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to second question:

```
var availableLocales = ['en', 'fr'];
var browserLocale = navigator.language.substring(0, 2);
var locale = availableLocales.indexOf(browserLocale) >= 0 browserLocale : 'en'; // 'en' is default locale
```